# Euclidian distance based fitness function

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Does it make sense to use euclidian distance as fitness function in order to maximise based on multiple parameters? If not what sort of fitness function should I be using for such a task?

Comment: This is too vague. What is your problem? It makes sense if the Euclidian distance means *something* for *some* parameter, which is not always the case. You need to provide more details.

Comment: The parameters are amount of similarity between two pieces of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your biggest problem using euclidean distance is that your multiple objectives might not be scaled the same way.  I.e. if objective A ranges from 1 to 1000, and objective B ranges from 0 to 1, you're going to favor objective A.  If you're wedded to using a single aggregate objective rather than an MOEA that does Pareto ranking like NSGAII, pay attention to objective scaling, and also consider a satisficing formulation.

Satisficing is where you saturate an objective at a certain good-enough value.  In Python, it might look like this (assuming minimization):

```
a_prime = max(a, 40)
b_prime = max(b, 0.1)
aggregate_objective = a_prime / 1000 + b_prime
```

Comment: If I value all objectives equally would normalising them suffice? And thanks for mentioning MOEA, I'll look into that.

Comment: Glad to help!  Normalizing is a bit subjective, but yes, basically.  If you value your objectives equally and you have some idea of their ranges, it's not going to hurt you to use a Euclidean metric on their normalized values.  People usually tweak the weights a few times after seeing the results of optimization.  This is a pretty reasonable thing to do and helps you understand the design space better.